# R - replacing words/phrases in Text

Tags: r

I have .csv file where I have created a custom dictionary to replace words and I uploaded this as a dataframe in R, for example:

```
word         replacement
Hello        Hi
Good         Best
Good Night   Sweet Morning
```

What I want to do is to scan my text in .csv and scan each cell and if it contains any of the words or phrase that is present in my custom dictionary then replace that word or phrase with the replacement.

Please help me with code, I am new to R.

Comment: What does your text file look like? Is it also a csv-file with columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Dictionary data frame
dict <- data.frame( original = c("word", "Hello","Good","Good Night"),         
                          replace = c("replacement", "Hi", "Best", "Sweet Morning"), 
                          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dict
#     original       replace
# 1       word   replacement
# 2      Hello            Hi
# 3       Good          Best
# 4 Good Night Sweet Morning

# Data frame where the words need to be replaced
df <- data.frame ( col1 = c( "Hello", "World", "Good","coffee"),
                   col2 = c("Good Night","To all my friends","I have no","word"), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df
#    col1              col2
#1  Hello        Good Night
#2  World To all my friends
#3   Good         I have no
#4 coffee              word

apply(df,
      MARGIN=c(1,2),
      FUN=function(x){ pos=which(dict[,1] == x); 
                                 if(length(pos)>0) return(dict[pos[1],2]) else return(x)})

#        col1     col2               
#[1,] "Hi"     "Sweet Morning"    
#[2,] "World"  "To all my friends"
#[3,] "Best"   "I have no"        
#[4,] "coffee" "replacement"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same dict and df as @Katia and `rflashtext` library:

```
dict <- data.frame( original = c("word", "Hello", "Good", "Good Night"),         
                    replace = c("replacement", "Hi", "Best", "Sweet Morning"), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dict

    original       replace
1       word   replacement
2      Hello            Hi
3       Good          Best
4 Good Night Sweet Morning

df <- data.frame ( col1 = c( "Hello", "World", "Good", "coffee"),
                   col2 = c("Good Night", "To all my friends", "I have no", "word"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df

    col1              col2
1  Hello        Good Night
2  World To all my friends
3   Good         I have no
4 coffee              word

library(rflashtext)

processor <- KeywordProcessor$new(keys = dict$original,
                                  words = dict$replace)

df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(column) processor$replace_keys(column))

df
    col1              col2
1     Hi     Sweet Morning
2  World To all my friends
3   Best         I have no
4 coffee       replacement
```